# Relationships for "Meetings" List

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a "people" table, and I have a "meetings" table, where there are two coloumns: Person1_ID and Person2_ID.

When I set up a meeting for person1_ID (the person is one of the "people") with Person2_ID (also, another person from the "people" table) the entry for the meeting is complete. However, this also means Person2_ID is meeting with Person1_ID as well; in other words, this is a two sided relationship.

How can I query "meetings" per each person? In a form, I want to display the "meetings" fpr each person separately however I'm not sure how I can pull the information out from my "meetings" table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your will find that your current design is probably not adequate for modelling the requirements of meeting management in real life.

At its most basic:

- A meeting is a single event that has a place, a time, a duration and a description.
- Multiple people may attend a meeting.

From these 2 simple requirements, you can see that, for a single meeting record, you need to be able to associate multiple `People` records, not just 2.

This can be modelled like this:

```
Meetings table                  MeetingsPeople table
------------------------        -----------------------
ID  (PK)        AUTONUMBER  ->  MeetingID (FK)   NUMBER
Description     TEXT            PersonID  (FK)   NUMBER
Location        TEXT
DateTimeStart   DATETIME
Duration        NUMBER
```

The `MeetingsPeople` table is very simple: it is used to link a given person to a given meeting.
This will remove the limitation you had. Now you can have as many people as needed for a meeting, not only 2.

If you want to record who initiated the meeting or if the other participants confirmed their attendance, you can add that to the `MeetingsPeople` table:

```
MeetingsPeople table
-----------------------
MeetingID (FK)   NUMBER
PersonID  (FK)   NUMBER
IsMeetingOwner   YES/NO
IsConfirmed      YES/NO
```

When you create a new `Meetings` record, you also need to create a new record in `MeetingsPeople` that links to the owner of the meeting.

To query all meetings being attended by a given person (to generate their schedule for instance) all you need is a simple query.
Say that *John Doe* has and `ID` of `123` in the `People` table and we want to know all the meetings he should attend today:

```
SELECT Meetings.*
FROM   Meetings
INNER JOIN MeetingsPeople
  ON MeetingsPeople.MeetingID = Meetings.ID
WHERE MeetingsPeople.PersonID = 123
      AND DateTimeStart >= Date()
ORDER BY DateTimeStart;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I would have never thought of this!