# inserting some values in one field

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, data-modeling

How can I insert many values into one database field?
Is it possible?

I want to make a table for **meetings**, and *invite* **many persons**. So how can I add persons to my meeting table?

Comment: One value per column is the way to go. Have several rows instead. One meeting table, with place, date etc, and one meetingattendands table, with meeting id and person id columns.

Comment: how i make a query which show me meetings of one person?

Comment: and thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to choose a many-to-many design. One person can go to many meetings, and many people can go to one meeting.

```
Meetings table:
- MeetingId (int)
- Date (DateTime)

People table:
- PersonId (int)
- Name (char)

PeopleInMeeting table:
- MeetingId (int)
- PersonId (char)
```

This way you can book many people in you meeting (with many records in PeopleInMeeting), o one person can book in many meetings (same way)

Answer (score 0):

### Entity

In a **[relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database)** each table stores a single type of record as row (e.g. a single `Meeting`, or a single `Person`, or a single `MeetingAttendance`). Each record (row) in a table has some columns, a **primary-key** (e.g. ID) plus different attributes (e.g. name, date, location). This concept is called **entity**.

### Relationship

Since for each type of record there is one **table**, you can now model the relationships between these records/tables using **foreign-keys** if its *one-to-one* (1:1) or *one-to-many* (1:n).  In your case a single `person` can visit/attend many `meeting`'s **and** a single `meeting` can be visited by many `person`s. So the relationship, lets name it `MeetingAttendance`, is **many-to-many (n:m)**. This n:m relationship is best modeled using a so called association-table, which stores both foreign-keys.

See similar question [Relationships for “Meetings” List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109877/relationships-for-meetings-list).

### Entity-Relationship (ER)

An [ER-model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) or ER-diagram depicts these relationships between entities.

So your ER-model will look like this:
[image: ER-diagram]